# Taking partial time derivative of a functional

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, coordinate-systems, change-of-variable

**Edit: I am so sorry. Apparently I made a huge mistake. Here is the final version of the question.**

Let us suppose we have a functional of f such that $f=f((\vec{r}(t),t)$ where $\vec{r}(t) = a(t)\vec{x}(t)$.

I am trying to derive an equation such that

$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_r = \left.\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right|_x + \left.\frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t}\right|_r \cdot \nabla_x  $$

where $\nabla_r = \frac{1}{a}\nabla_x$

It is actually about coordinate transformation.

[image]

Comment: It should be $$\frac{\color{red}d f}{\color{blue}d t}$$ on the LHS, no partial derivatives. And this is just a straight forward application of the chain rule $$f'= \partial_{t} f + \partial_{x_{1}} f \cdot x_{1}' + \partial_{x_{2}} f \cdot x_{2}' + \dots$$ then use that $x_{i}' = q_{i} a'$.

Comment: @mattos There is no total derivative actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like this exhibits exactly why people shouldn't use thermodynamic notation.

Anyway. I am going to introduce an auxiliary variable to make the change clear. You have two coordinate systems $(\vec{r},\tau)$ and $(\vec{x},t)$, related by 
$$ \tau = t, \qquad \vec{r} = a(t) \vec{x} $$

What you write as $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{\vec{r}}$ is the partial derivative $\partial_\tau$ in the $(\vec{r},\tau)$ coordinates, and the derivative $ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big|_{\vec{x}}$ is the partial derivative $\partial_t$ in the $(\vec{x},t)$ coordinates.

Standard coordinate transformation tells you

$$ \partial_\tau = \frac{\partial t}{\partial\tau} \partial_t + \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial \tau}\cdot \nabla_{\vec{x}} $$

The change of variables can be rewritten in the form 
$$ t = \tau, \qquad \vec{x} = \vec{r} / a(\tau) $$
and hence 
$$ \frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau} = 1 \qquad \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial \tau} = - \vec{r} \frac{\dot{a}(\tau)}{a^2(\tau)} $$